# TypeError: fetch failed during Next.js project build

Tags: next.js, vercel

I got this error during Vercel deployment:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000
  }
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/match". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I guess probably is because of the `http://localhost:3000/api/event`, how can I replace a correct url to `localhost`?

```js
async function getData(): Promise<Events[]> {
  const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/event`, {
    cache: "no-cache",
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs if you try to call your internal API route from a server component at build time, where there is no application running (the application being build and not deployed yet). Tim Neutkens from Next.js [points that out on a GitHub issue with a similar error](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44062#issuecomment-1544028776):

> This is because you're trying to fetch from an internal api route during build, which is not supported.

Instead of calling the internal API route from a server component, which then calls your DB or CMS, reach them directly from the component. It helps avoid the error, and also an additional useless API call.

---

That has been said, if the API is not your internal one, you can replace

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/event')
```

with

```js
fetch(process.env.URL + '/api/even')
```

and create an `.env` file in which you add:

```
URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Then on the Vercel dashboard, you set an `URL` environment variable with your production URL.

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely occurring due to the usage of the `http://localhost:3000/api/event` URL in your code when deploying to Vercel. When your application is in deployment mode, the `localhost` address no longer refers to your own system, and you should use the actual server address where your API resides.

To resolve this issue, it's better to use environment variables to determine the API address. In development and testing environments, you can use `http://localhost:3000`, but when deploying to Vercel, you should use the Vercel server's address to access the API.

For example, you can utilize environment variables within Vercel. First, define environment variables in your Vercel settings. Create an environment variable named `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` and set its value to your API address (e.g., `https://your-api-domain.com`).

Then, in your code, use the `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` environment variable for API communication:

```js
async function getData(): Promise<Events[]> {
  const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL; // Using an environment variable
  const data = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/event`, {
    cache: "no-cache",
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return data;
}
```

With these changes, your application should be able to correctly communicate with the API in all environments (development, testing, deployment), and the ECONNREFUSED error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by substituting `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

More details can be found in the related [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44062).

Answer (score 0):

In my case

my **`Data Fetching`** function is like that

[image]

my **`.env`** is like that

[image]

now when i run **`npm run build`** it showing following error while i am **`developing`** the application.

[image]

my server is running on **`localhost:3000`**

so the error is because i am using external api if we make same **`hostname`** like **`localhost`** then the issue will be resolved.

for example i create api with same response on **`http://localhost:4000/todos`** so its working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me

Next 14.1

it doesn't matter if you use 127.0.0.1 or localhost, it works both ways
in fecth() I don't use cache:'no-store', only route.
The route (route.js) and the page (page.js) have to be dynamic.

The solution is to add this line in both files:

**export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';**

TypeScript I have not tested

Answer (score 0):

face the same issue with that
solution is add this line in file

```
***export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';***
```

Next 14.1

Comment: Is this answer any different from [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77968031/12567365) already provided by @Juan? If so, how does it differ? (Also, does the code in your answer really need those asterisks?)