# NextJS 13: Setting cookies on the client from an API route

Tags: cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Using NextJS 13, I am trying to set a cookie on the client from an API route. The API route sets the cookie like this

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    // ...
    const response = NextResponse.json({}, { status: 200 })
    response.cookies.set({
        name: 'name',
        value: 'value',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false, // development
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
    })
    return response
}
```

Then, in a **server component**, I make a call to this endpoint:

```
export default async function SomeComponent() {
    const response = await requestAPI() // Requests the above API endpoint
    return <div>...</div>
}
```

However, no cookie is received on the client side, and the `Set-Cookie` header is also not present. This seems to be happening since I am using a server component. If I use a client component, like so:

```
'use client'

import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function SomeComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function request() {
            await requestAPI()
        }

        request()
    }, [])

    return <div>...</div>
}
```

then the cookie is received and the header is present in the response.

My question is: how can I "relay" the cookie from the server component to the client?

Comment: Your API route is most not to be called by a server component. Check out the answer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905386/typeerror-fetch-failed-during-next-js-project-build).